# perl date fetch script assistance

Tags: perl

I was just having a go at perl. I was trying to extract the date and time from a line in a text file that begins with

> Date:    05/Feb/2017 21:30:00 PST - 06/Feb/2017 06:00:00 PST

I have managed to scavenge a script but Im trying to modify it so it extracts the above to

```
start date - 2017-02-05 21:30:00
end date   - 2017-02-06 06:00:00
```

any help would be appreciated

```
 #Is it a reg date
    } elsif (!$start && $line[$i] =~ /^Date: (.+?) - (.+)$/i) {
        $regstartdate = $1;
        $regenddate = $2;

    } elsif (!$start && $line[$i] =~ /^Date: (.+)$/i) {
        #Monday 3rd July 2006
        #Friday 30th June 2006 01:00 Hrs EST
        $regstartdate = $1;

        eval{
            $start = &dateconv($regstartdate);
            $end = $start;
            1;
        }
        or do{
           warn "Could not process start date: $regstartdate";
        };
    } elsif (!$start && $line[$i] =~ /^Time:\s*(\d+:\d+)[\s\-]+\s+(\d+:\d+)\s+[hH][rR][sS]\s+(\w+)$/i) {
        $tz = $3;
        $twestartdate = $regstartdate . " ".$1." Hrs ".$3;
        $tweenddate = $regenddate . " ".$2." Hrs ".$3;
        $start = &dateconv($regstartdate);
        $end = &dateconv($regenddate);

    } elsif (!$start && $line[$i] =~ /^Time:\s*(\d+:\d+)[\s*\-]+\s*(\d+:\d+)\s+(\w+)$/i) {
        $tz = $3;
        $regstartdate = $regstartdate . " ".$1." Hrs ".$3;
        $regenddate = $regenddate . " ".$2." Hrs ".$3;
        $start = &dateconv($regstartdate);
        $end = &dateconv($regenddate);

    #Is it a reg Time
    } elsif (!$start && $line[$i] =~ /^Interruption Time: (\d+:\d+)[\s\-]+(\d+:\d+) (\w+)/i) {
        $regstartdate = $regstartdate . " " . $1 . " Hrs " . $3;
        $regenddate = $regenddate . " " . $2 . " Hrs " . $3;


        $start = &dateconv($regstartdate);
        $end = &dateconv($regenddate);

    #Is is the start time ?
    } elsif (!$start && $line[$i] =~ /^Duration:\s*START DATE (.*)/i) {
      $start = &dateconv($1);

    #Is it the end time ?
    } elsif (!$end && $line[$i] =~ /^END DATE (.*)/i) {
      my $endtime = $1;
      $end = &dateconv($endtime);
      $endtime =~ m/(\w{1,2}ST)/g;
      $tz = $1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Offering a solution using `Time::Piece` which I prefer - both because I like the interface, but also because it's core as of perl 5.9.5

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;

my $input_format  = '%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S';
my $output_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S';

while (<DATA>) {
   if ( my ( $start_str, $end_str ) = m/Date: (.*) PST - (.*) PST/ ) {
      my $start = Time::Piece->strptime( $start_str, $input_format );
      my $end   = Time::Piece->strptime( $end_str,   $input_format );

      print "Start:\t", $start->strftime($output_format), "\n";
      print "End:  \t", $end  ->strftime($output_format), "\n";
   }
}


__DATA__
Date: 05/Feb/2017 21:30:00 PST - 06/Feb/2017 06:00:00 PST
```

The reason I like it is because the `$start` and `$end` in the above, are 'time objects' so you can do things like:

```
print $start -> epoch;
print "Elapsed time: ", $end - $start, "s\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime) module, parsing and formatting those date strings is trivial:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use DateTime;
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;

my $fmt = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(pattern => '%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S');

my $line = 'Date: 05/Feb/2017 21:30:00 PST - 06/Feb/2017 06:00:00 PST';
$line =~ s/^Date: //;
my @dates = split(/\s*-\s*/, $line);

for my $date (@dates) {
    my $dt = $fmt->parse_datetime($date);
    say $dt->ymd . ' ' . $dt->hms;
}
```

Produces:

```
2017-02-05 21:30:00
2017-02-06 06:00:00
```

You can adjust the formatting as you see fit.

Comment: i think i broke the script now?

Comment: @perln00b I have no idea. Did you?

Comment: I've tended to use `Time::Piece` on account of it being core as of 5.9.5.  But the functionality of it is similar `my $t = Time::Piece->strptime($time_str, $format );`

Comment: @Sobrique I like the fact that it's core, but the poor time zone handling and lack of manipulation features make it not worth the hassle for me.

Comment: Timezone is fair enough - it took a bit of faff to parse `PST`. What do you mean by manipulation features though?

Comment: @Sobrique Sure, so something like `$dt->truncate(to => 'month')->subtract(days => 1)` to get the last day of the previous month.

Comment: Well, there isn't a truncate, but: `$start -= $start->day_of_month * ONE_DAY;` Or perhaps something like: `$start = $start -> add_months(-1); $start += ONE_DAY * ($start -> month_last_day - $start -> day_of_month);` It's not like it's totally crippled in that regard.

Comment: so this essentially takes the raw data from an html email file which has the date in the format

Date: 05/Feb/2017 21:30:00 PST - 06/Feb/2017 06:00:00 PST

Comment: so the code that was working earlier, was the Time::Piece script which I added more details to above. that was meant to fetch the date and time from this

  Duration:    START DATE Wednesday 28th September 2011 23:59 Hrs PST
     END DATE Thursday 29th September 2011 06:00 Hrs PST

I dont want to change the libraries and risk breaking it. could you give me any pointers on how to make changes so that it can fetch the date from the new format

appreciate it heaps

Comment: @perln00b This is getting too long for a discussion in the comments. If you have a different problem, you should ask a new question. Be sure to include a self-contained test case that reproduces the problem (a [mcve]).